# TextAlignment is not working dynamically for checkbox

Tags: android, textview, text-alignment, android-checkbox, android-gravity

Android.Views.Textalignment is not working dynamically

I have tried the below code:

In load time:

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
checkBox.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.ViewStart;
```

Dynamically change the alignment in a button click. But alignment not updated.

```
checkBox.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.Center;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to change the alignment of the text in the `CheckBox`. This can be achieved by setting the widget's `gravity` to `center` in through code.

```
checkBox.setGravity( Gravity.CENTER )
```

Comment: he is asking for dynamic way not on xml

Comment: Gravity works fine. But I need TextAlginment property.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Check Box"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"/>
```

**make sure to use the width as match_parent ,

or a fixed size creater than the size of the checkbox text,

then you can use the textAlignment as center or anything you want**